# Meaning of commas in set notation

Tags: notation

Let $X=\{ x\in X: x \text{ satisfies condition } A, x \text{ satisfies condition } B\}$. Does the comma in above set notation mean that $x$ has to statisfy $A$ and $B$ at the same time or only one of those; so that we have: $X$ is the union of $X_A=\{ x \text{ satisfies} A\}$ and $X_B=\{ x \text{ satisfies} B\}$?

Comment: Usually it must satisfy both.

Comment: It's used in place of *and*.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have given a name to your object $x,$ the notation is reserved to this $x$. So you have to read "$X$ is the set of elements $x$ such that *this* $x$ satisfy condition $A$ and *this* $x$ satisfy condition $B.$ For example,
$$X=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\,:\,n\text{ is even}, n\text{ is odd}\}=\varnothing.$$

Comment: You are welcome !

Comment: Why did you explicitly write that the empty set is part of that set?

Comment: I gave an example of a set of the form described in the question, and remarked that the set was actually empty.